# Compute Limit of an infinite sum

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis

Assume $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f_n(x)=0$ for every n=1,2,...
and  $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\dfrac{f_{n+1}(x)}{f_n(x)}=0$ for every n=1,2,...
Does it follow that $\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f_n(x)=0$?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm not convinced your second condition is enough for the sum to converge for any finite $x$: imagine each ratio taking twice as long as the previous to fall below $1$. I'm not convinced either way, but strongly suspect you need uniformity of some sort.

Comment: Maybe something like the Cauchy condensation test could be useful.

Comment: You have $f_{n+1}(x)/f_n(x) < 1/2$ for large enough $x$ for every $n$.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take $$f_{n}\left(x\right)=\frac{n!}{x^{n}}$$
 then, for each $n$
 $$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}\left(x\right)=0,\,\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f_{n+1}\left(x\right)}{f_{n}\left(x\right)}=0$$
 but$$\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{n!}{x^{n}}=\infty.$$

Comment: I see. Thanks Marco.